# Estimating model parameters in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a set of value pairs (x,y) I want to fit them to the following model so that squared error is minimized. What is the easiest way to do so in R:

Y = (A*(N+1-X)^b) / X^a, where N is max(y), A,a,b are various parameters

The above one is Rank ordering distribution (see http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0004791&representation=PDF)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: An approach is shown in http://www.r-bloggers.com/learning-r-parameter-fitting-for-models-involving-differential-equations/

Comment: Please include a reproducible example and the code that's giving you problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are willing to do a linear regression : `log Y = b log A + b log (N+1-X) - a log X`

In this context I would create say `YY = log Y`, `X1 = log(N+1-X)` and `X2 = log X` and go with `lm(YY ~ X1 + X2)`

Comment: This wouldn't minimize the squared error on the original scale. You seemed to have dropped the `b log A` term from your model but I think it should have just been log(A) in the first place...

Comment: I guess in a first order approximation it is the same : Y = Ym + e ; then log(Y) - log(Ym) = e/Ym + o(e/Ym). Concerning the constant term it is automatically included by lm, otherwise it is lm(YY ~ I(-1) + X1 + X2)

Comment: Thanks @clemlaflemme looks like a viable solution. Will upload the code as  I write at my side.